# Java println() of integers?

Tags: java, println

I want to print the two integer variables divided.

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
System.out.println(a + b);
```

Obviously println() function processes them as integers and calculates the sum.
Instead I would like the output becomes like this "12". Any ideas?

Comment: a * 10 + b should do    ;-)

Comment: System.out.println(String.valueOf(a) + String.vlaueOf(b));

Answer (score 0):

Insert some blank Strings to induce this:

```
System.out.println(a +""+ b);
```

Comment: Not sure why is it downvoted as it's the same as the accepted answer in the duplicate link.

Answer (score -2):

Store the integers as strings:

```
String a = "1";
String b = "2";
String c = a + b;

System.out.println(c);
```